# typeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'paths' of object for compilerOptions in tsconfig

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

```
**Trying to set the path inside tsconfig.json for compiler to treat src as baseUrl in react typescript project**

  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
    "include": [
       "src"
     ]
  }
```

**But getting error as below:**

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'paths' of object '#<Object>'
    at verifyTypeScriptSetup (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239:43)
```

Is this because of the folder permission or anything missing in the configuration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, there's a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9868) in Create-React-App@4.0.0.

The workaround that solved for me was:

Downgrade `react-scripts`:

```
yarn add react-scripts@3.4.4
```

Create a `paths.json` in the project's root:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@Components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Add an `extends` to `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, wasted so much time on this

Comment: You saved me so much time thank you. UPVOTED. but they should fix this

Comment: Seems fixed in version 4.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Per the GitHub issue, if you just delete the tsconfig.json file then run "npm start" it will recreate the tsconfig.json file for you and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the following change:

As was previously mentioned, deleting your tsconfig and letting it auto-create a default one also fixes the issue. If you're like me, though, you may have been alarmed for a second that you can only use the default config, with the workaround breaking your base path for absolute imports. (not so - phew!)

Specifically, the setting I had that was breaking post-upgrade was compileOnSave, which is no longer necessary to specify.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @DrShaffopolis!! Recently I have upgraded `"react-scripts"` to `"^4.0.1"`, and making changes as proposed above worked for me. +1